# Cannot call web service when deploying ASP.NET site to the server but can run on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to run an ASP.NET site by calling a webservice in the sub virtual directory, I get the error below:

**"The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized. "**

This is the code that I wrote:

```
Dim ws As Odyssey.SupportServices.SupportServices
ws = New Odyssey.SupportServices.SupportServices
ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

My virtual directory structure is shown below:

CSACCsupp  - **Parent** :   The parent can call webservice without any issues.
Odyssey - **Sub** :     The Sub cannot call webservice as shown in the error above.

I think the problem is in the IIS security. Therefore, I went through the IIS security and compared the parent and sub; they are identical.

I really do not know what to do next as I've tried many ways to set the security in IIS, but I am still in the dark.

Could you please suggest on this issue?

Comment: You should post your web.config, especially the authentication/authorization settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are the apps running in the same AppPool?  If not, what account are they each running under?  Are the web.config files identical?  Maybe you are setting impersonation in one and not the other?

Comment: It is run in the same app pool. it uses the system id, i don't know either. But the problem is when I try to call webservice from the server, it did not send system id to the webservice. Whereas, when I call website in localhost(my PC) and call webservice in the server, it sent my id into the webservice. Could you please help explain why it is different.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't posted web.config yet.  If the app is sending your ID to the web service that means it using impersonation, or the appPool is using your credentials to run.  Either set this up the same way on the server, or turn on impersonation in web.config, or add permissions for the default ASP.NET identity to the webservice server.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your files ntfs permissions, sometimes when copying files windows keeps the original permissions of the files instead of the new ones.

So probably your files e.g. web.config may not have the necessary permission.

Comment: I have checked permission, it is the same setting.
It is very weired that I could call webservice from parent folder.
On the other hand, I could not call webservice from sub folder.
I have setup Web Virtual Directory for both Parent and Sub folder to use the same app pool.

Could you please help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.:)